# Parameter passed from a child of p:timeline is null in action method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

**My goal:** I like to add some commandLink as a child of PrimeFaces `p:timeline` The user should be able to click one of those links. The click shall invoke a method in my bean (CDI, ViewScoped). In the action method I need information from the clicked item in the timeline. Depending on the outcome of the action method there there might be a navigation to a different UI.

**My attempt:**
The full form is quite short and simple. So I better post it entirely:

```
<h:form>
  <p:fieldset legend="Upcoming Gates">
    <p:timeline height="200px" style="width: 99%;"
           start="#{facilitatorCockpit.timelineStart}"
           end="#{facilitatorCockpit.timelineEnd}"
           value="#{facilitatorCockpit.timelineModel}"
           var="timelineitem"
           selectable="false"
           zoomable="false"
           moveable="false"                                
           >     
       <h:outputText value="#{timelineitem.systemElement}"/> <br/>
       <p:commandLink action="#{facilitatorCockpit.openStatusSheet(timelineitem.roadmapId)}"
                               process="@this"  value="#{timelineitem.roadmapId}"
                               title="Open Status Sheet"/>         
    </p:timeline>
  </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

**Current behaviour:**
As one can see in the xhtml, I am displaying some "Id" on the timeline item. This id shows up correctly in the UI. The action method is executed, but the passed parameter is resolved to `null` on the server side.

I am using the very same attempt from inside a datatable (same UI, just a different form), where it works fine. I am just not able to call a action method with parameter(s) like this from inside of `p:timeline`

No nested forms on my page, no JavaScript errors visislbe in the browsers console. I also tried all combinations of commandLink / button and action/listener, even though the one used in the example is excatly what I want, but with the same results.

I am using PF 6.0 and Mojarra 2.2.10

**Update**: I noticed some slighty difference in the generated HTML to the generated HTML when I am using this kind of commandLink e.g. in a datatable.

In `p:timeline` the very same identifier and JavaScript calls are generated for every single timeline item:

```
<a id="j_idt88:j_idt94" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget" 
   aria-label="Open Status Sheet" 
   onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt88:j_idt94&quot;,p:&quot;j_idt88:j_idt94&quot;});
            return false;" 
   title="Open Status Sheet">FPR 137
</a>
<!-- .... -->
<a id="j_idt88:j_idt94" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget"
    aria-label="Open Status Sheet" 
    onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt88:j_idt94&quot;,p:&quot;j_idt88:j_idt94&quot;});
           return false;"
    title="Open Status Sheet">FPR 138
```

**Current Solution:**
Based on the accepted answer my current approach now looks like this:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{facilitatorCockpit.openStatusSheetFromTimeline()}"
    process="@this"
    value="#{timelineitem.phase.label}"
    title="Open Status Sheet"
>         
   <f:param name="id" value="#{timelineitem.roadmapId}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I added an additional action method to the backing bean which delegates to the original one.

```
public String openStatusSheetFromTimeline() {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap();
    String roadmapId = params.get("id");
    Long id = Long.parseLong(roadmapId);
    return openStatusSheet(id);
}
```

Still I am just wondering what's wrong with the inital approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not you use the

`<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{facilitatorCockpit.onSelect}"/>` ?

Into the onSelect-method you can call openStatusSheet or refactore openStatusSheet for `TimelineSelectEvent`. The id can you save in the data-attribute.

```
public void onSelect(TimelineSelectEvent e) {  
    TimelineEvent timelineEvent = e.getTimelineEvent();  

    // get your Id
    String roadmapId = timelineEvent.getDate.toString();
}
```

**Edit: Second solution**

For submit the id with custom components use `p:commandButton` with `f:param`.

```
    <p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{timelineBean.model}"
        height="250px" selectable="true" var="item">

        <p:commandButton value="Click #{item}"
            actionListener="#{timelineBean.click()}">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{item}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:timeline>
```

And into your backing bean can you catch the param like

```
public void click() {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String roadmapId = params.get("id");

    ...
}
```

So you can insert 2 or more commmandButtons.

Comment: tyvm for your answer. Might be a compromise for the current situation. However, there are several problems with it. Main point is that I expect changes of the UI where more than one command link shall be added to a single timeline event. when I use the select event of the timeline I will lose this option.

Comment: That's right. I added a second solution for this use case.

Comment: Passing the parameter with f:param did the trick! Still don't know why it does not work with the initial approach in my question, though.

Answer (score 0):

it means what your timelineitem.roadmapId is null , also make your managed bean ViewScope or Session Scope. print parameter before pass.

Comment: The bean *is* ViewScoped. In the UI the correct id is displayed as label on the timeline item.